# Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении "Бог давно отвернулся..."

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Верно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении: "Бог давно  отвернулся от нас, а может, и сам учудил всё это, чтобы избавиться от стыда за то, что создали его любимые люди. Он хочет стереть нас с лица земли, как страшный сон"?

Comment: Текст хочется стереть. Может быть контекст даст шанс этому страшному сну.

Comment: Не поняла вас...

Comment: Кое-что поняли, раз внесли изменения. Не понимаете, что такое контекст?

Comment: @shampar, почему вы со мной так грубо говорите?

Comment: "Не" было лишнее - механическая ошибка

Comment: Нас не много, я один Вам пишу.

Comment: @NaraMamedova Текст действительно тяжелый стилистически, но пунктуация тут довольно прозрачна. Пунктуационных ошибоу у вас не было, если не считать лишнего пробела после открывающей кавычки (убрал его).

Answer (score 1):

Можно предложить такое редактирование:

***Бог давно отвернулся от нас, а может, и сам устроил всё это, чтобы избавиться от стыда за всё содеянное его людьми. Он хочет стереть нас с лица земли и забыть как страшный сОн?***

Или:

***Бог давно отвернулся от нас, а может, и сам устроил всё это из чувства стыда за всё содеянное его людьми.***

Пояснение

1) **Исправлена стилистика и упрощена грамматика.**

Это речь персонажа, поэтому в ней нежелательно применять сложные грамматические конструкции. Разговорная речь должна быть краткой и выразительной, она же воспринимается на слух.

Подбор лексики по стилю и по семантике должен быть более тщательным, а также  должен соответствовать теме. Глагол ***учудил***  ближе к просторечию; ***любимые люди*** звучит с  иронией, но она здесь не совсем у места.

***Стереть с лица земли как страшный сон*** – сочетаемость некорректная. Сон можно забыть или стереть из сознания.

2) **Сравнительный оборот обособляется факультативно**. В предложенном варианте обособления нет, так как на него падает ударение в конце вопросительной фразы.

Answer (score 0):

Все ошибки:

А может - союз + вводное слово. (запятая после `может`)

**Ещё один важный момент.**

Есть 2 варианта - можно выделить запятой оборот "как страшный сон", а можно не выделять. Это подтверждается в гугл-книгах (литературная база гугл), где присутствуют оба варианта.

Разница:

`С запятой` - это обычное сравнение - *стереть, как стирают страшные сны из памяти*.

(Не сильно подходит, так как сны не стирают, а забывают.)

`Без запятой` смысл более глубокий - *стереть людей, являющихся страшным сном в понимании кого-то*.

Второй вариант очень актуален для данного текста.

Comment: всё-таки просто так вы говорить не будете... Но, мне кажется, запятая после "может" здесь не нужна, так как Союз + члены предложения. Знаки препинания ставятся в соответствии с правилами пунктуационного оформления синтаксических конструкций с союзом «а».
Сейчас он замкнут, а может быть и очень разговорчивым в компании близких друзей.

Comment: Нужна однозначно. Можно заменить на "вероятно", "возможно". Если без запятой, то должен быть инфинитив: может быть - ваш пример; может летать; может что-то делать. Самая простая проверка - заменить на слово "умеет". Это не наш случай. А вот перед "как", думаю, лучше без запятой: даже при чтении там пауза не делается. Или вы делаете паузу? В принципе, это и есть лучшая проверка, чтобы правильно определить. Но смысл у этих двух вариантов очень отличается.